# Coding a QR Code/test possible in xCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, qr-code, tabbar

I want to create a QR-Reader App that is a two page Application. Both are accessible with a tab bar. The first page should be the QR reader part. The second should store the read QR codes in images.
I have a QR-Reader already coded, but i don´t know how to test the iPhone app on my Mac. Is that even possible?
And my second question:
How can i save the result of my scanned codes in the other page?

Answer (score 4):

iOS 7 now has the ability to detect QR codes and other barcodes directly. There is a sample app built right into the Xcode help system that shows how to use it. I'm on a different machine right now so I can't seem to find the app. I'll take a look on my other Mac and post an edit if I can find the sample code.

EDIT: I was mistaken. The sample App is not from Apple, its an open source GitHub project.

The link is:

[**Sample project to recognize QR codes**](https://github.com/ShinobiControls/iOS7-day-by-day/blob/master/16-qr-codes-avfoundation/16-qr-codes-avfoundation.md)

Be sure to look at the other postings from this company. They all look very good.

(A link to other projects in the iOS 7 series:

[**iOS 7 Day By Day**](https://github.com/ShinobiControls/iOS7-day-by-day)

You might want to use that rather than custom QR reader code.)

As to how to test QR code scanning from your Mac, that's going to be a problem. QR scanning involves using the built-in camera, and the simulator does not let you use a Mac camera as an iOS camera. I think you will probably have to do your testing on an actual iOS device.

As to how to "...save the result of my scanned codes in the other page" that depends. Do you want to save a picture of the QR code, or the text information that comes from decoding it?

If you want to save a picture then you would need to code your QR scanner to capture the image as a UIImage, and then pass that to your second view controller. You could do that in the prepareForSegue method that links to your second view controller, assuming you're using storyboards.

The same basic technique would apply if you want to pass the text info from the QR code.

You need to provide a better description of how your app is structured and what you want to do if you want specific help with that, but that sounds like a more generic "how do I pass info from one view controller to another" type question, of which there are hundreds here on SO.

Comment: If you find that sample app I'd appreciate a link, or at least its name. I've seen third party demo apps like [this one](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx) but not one included with Xcode.

Comment: I remembered incorrectly. The sample app is not from Apple, it's an open source sample project from Githhub. The link is https://github.com/ShinobiControls/iOS7-day-by-day/blob/master/16-qr-codes-avfoundation/16-qr-codes-avfoundation.md  I also edited my original post.

Comment: @Tom, no problem. BTW, it took me less than 10 minutes to modify that sample app so it would detect all the different types of bar codes that iOS 7 supports. There are 10 different types of 1 dimensional and 2 dimensional codes it supports. I just had to look up the whole list of types and pass them all in in the call to setMetadataObjectTypes, and then change the code that handles found codes to accept any type of code, not just QR codes.

Comment: Hey Duncan C,
thank you for your answer! I just want to save the text data from the QR code.

Comment: i am using xcode 7.3.1 and swift 2, which one pod i install it gives me an error in lib files on runtime. could anyone suggest which pod/lib i should use for swift2?

Comment: Not to be difficult, but my STRONG suggestion is to not use Swift 2. It's not source-compatible with the current version of the language, and over time it is going to get more and more out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your QR code reader detect if it's the simulator. If it is, it could just give you an image picker, or even just choose a hardcoded test image, and have the QR reader examine that image. However you can't fully test the functionality in the simulator, so you would basically have to test on a real device to make sure it truly works correctly. You would never want to release an app that's only been tested in the simulator anyway.

As for saving the result of the scanned codes, you just need to implement a data model (could be `NSMutableArray`, for example) that you have access to from both view controllers. When you switch to the second tab, it could check this array each time it is about to appear to update its state. You could probably add this array to both views in your app delegate in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method. Just get your root view controller from the window, which should be your tab bar controller, and get the view controllers from the tab bar.